# Find the pdf of Z=X/Y

Tags: random-variables, transformation

It is given that
$$pdf(x)=\lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x}$$
for $x\geq0$ and elsewhere it is zero. Next,
It is given that
$$pdf(y)=\lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 y}$$
for $y\geq0$ and elsewhere it is zero. Assume that $x$ and $y$ are i.i.d.I need to find the pdf of $Z=X/Y$. Can someone give me hints or redirect me to some source. I has been a while since I have dealt transformation of random variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CDF of a ratio of exponential variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33778/cdf-of-a-ratio-of-exponential-variables); [Ratio of exponential distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156808/ratio-of-exponential-distributions).

Comment: They are NOT i.i.d. if $\lambda_1\ne\lambda_2.$ Maybe you meant "Assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent." And you should take care to distinguish between $X$ and $x.$ Without doing that, you can't even understand things like $\Pr(X\le x). \qquad$